# Speed up Batch file processing, moving file to folder of same name

Tags: file, batch-file, directory, move

I need some help moving files into folders of the same name.  I have a batch file that works but it is very slow.  I'm moving approximately 3300 .xlsx files into folders with like names.  Here is what I have thus far:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd "C:\New folder"
FOR %%G IN (*.xlsx) DO (
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%a IN ("%%G") do (
set "outFolder=%%a "
for /D %%i in (*.*) do (
  for /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%b IN ("%%i") do (
    if "%%a"=="%%b" set "outFolder=%%i"
  )
 )
if not exist "!outfolder!" md "!outfolder!"
move "%%G" "!outfolder!"
)
)
popd
pause
```

Again this works but is slow.  This code moves the files to folder and if folder doesn't exist it creates it.

I have found this code and it works to a point.  The following code does not seem to recognize the folders that already exist and instead creates a folder even though one already exists.  Example:  I have file 123456 Action List.xlsx that I would like to go to folder 123456 Health Center.  The first code will accomodate that but is extremely slow and gets slower as it goes along.  Here is the second code:

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *.xlsx') do (
set "filename1=%%~i"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "folder1=!filename1:~0,6!"
mkdir "!folder1!" 2>nul
move "!filename1!" "!folder1!" >nul
endlocal
)
```

Any help is appreciated.

@Squashman - I'll try to explain a little better...

```
123456 Action List.xlsx
123456 Reportcard.xlsx
123456 CHCUP.xlsx
123456 Combo3.xlsx

123457 Action List.xlsx
123457 Reportcard.xlsx
123457 CHCUP.xlsx
123457 Combo3.xlsx
```

Each month I end up with ~3300 files like this after running various macros.  I have folders like "123456 Health Center" and "123457 MLK Center" already set up.  What I'm trying to do is move all of those .xlsx files into the corresponding folder.  That first code set works but like I said its slow.  What its doing is looking to see if there are corresponding file and folder names based on first 6 characters.  If there is it moves the file to that folder.

The second code is MUCH faster but it doesnt like the second part of the folder name i.e. "Health Center or MLK Center" from my examples and it then creates its own file with just the number portion i.e. 123456 or 123457 from my example.

Does that help?

Comment: I am not sure why you are doing what you are doing with all those `FOR ` commands.  Could you please provide an example of some input file names and how you want the output to look.  Please update your question by editing it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it might be better suited on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Save this script as *test.bat* in a folder with other .bat files, and run from open Cmd Prompt. **Replace** *dir* value with the path to your folder with XLSX files. The script assumes, target folders in which the files are sorted are created in the *dir* folder. Let me know if any errors.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "dir=C:\XLSX_Folder"
pushd "%dir%"
for /f "tokens=*" %%I in ('dir /b /a:-d "*.xlsx"') do (
    if not exist "%%~nI" md "%%~nI" 2>nul
    move "%%I" "%%~nI" >nul )
popd
exit /b
```

Comment: If the script works for you and you'll need more help in the future, pls  **Upvote** and **Accept** the answer by clicking both _Arrow Up_ and _Select_ signs to the left of the _Answer Box_.  Some novices don't know about these helpful features. :)

Comment: Well it almost works.  It looks at the entire filename and if a folder with that specific name doesn't exist it creates one.  What I'm trying to do is have it look at first 6 characters.  So I have a file 123456 Action List.xlsx and a folder exists with name 123456 Health Center.  I want to put that .xlsx file in the 123456 Health Center folder.  Does that make sense?